# jQuery UI - wrong droppable area when droppable area is rotated with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI's drag and drop...it is mostly working, however the droppable area does not match up with the shape of the droppable div in the browser...the droppable div has a CSS rotation applied to it...the dragged item appears to enter the div on two of the sides but on the top and left sides jQuery UI thinks the element has entered the droppable div outside of where the div is on the page...

I have created a CodePen that demonstrates the issue... [CodePen of jQuery UI draggable-droppable bug](http://codepen.io/michaelwhyte/pen/dpLqow)

```
var $moveBox = $('.move-box');
var $dropBox = $('.drop-box');

$moveBox.draggable();

$dropBox.droppable({
drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass('highlight');

  },

over: function( event, ui ) {
$( this )
  .addClass('highlight');
},

out: function( event, ui ) {
  $( this )
  .removeClass('highlight');
}

});
```

If you try the pen you will notice the red box enters the droppable box early on two of the sides...

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated...

Comment: I believe that jQuery will not be able to properly read the bounding rec of a rotated object correctly. I think you will need to feed it a recalculated bounding box. If you take a look at yourObject.getBoundingClientRect() you can get an idea of what is going on.